# How to skip rest of line using BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

In my program users frequently search a .txt file for certain information. To know if the right bit of data has been found I first check each line to see if it starts with a special character signalling the start of a group of data, something like this:

```
//one character has so far been read
if(character == '#'){
    //continue to examine data
}else{
    //skip the rest of the line
}
```

The problem I'm having is how to actually "skip the rest of the line", if the line did not start with my special character of choice.

As per complaints about insufficient information: I am indeed using a while loop to read each line

Comment: If only there were some way to `continue` to the next iteration of the loop. But that's just a pipe dream...

Comment: As Jack said you can use `continue` keyword. You should compare string by `.equals()` method. If you show how you are reading file and your input, it will be easy for us to understand problem exactly.

Comment: Why use a `BufferedReader` to read one _character_ at at time?

Comment: @smit you nearly fooled, me too; '#' is not a string, it is a character and shoul dbe compared with ==

Comment: @fge I'm reading more than just single characters, but that's after the first character has been confirmed

Comment: @AlexWien Yes your are right. but given OPs code block and not knowing input txt file how it looks like. It will be hard to give answer.

Comment: @Albin  I have enough information i do the same (but exactly th e oppposite) see running code below in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the action inside the if:

```
   BufferedReader csvFile = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

   while ((csvLine = csvFile.readLine()) != null) {
        if (csvLine.charAt(0) == '#') {
             // do # data action here
        }
   }
```

Comment: @fge remove the downvote: charAt delivers a char!!!!!! Source code: of java.langString: public char charAt(int index) {..} (java 1.5): by ethe way this source is running for yoears in prdouctive environment, so think before you downvote!

Comment: I have already removed it (but the `if (!condition) continue;` still applies however)

Comment: It works without continue: if he finds a "#" he makes something, else nothing! This code running code. But usually if we founda "#" we dont want to do anything becvause it is a comment in my file formats, but he wants to do an action when he founds an "#"

Comment: @AlexWien Thank you, your answer was most helpful

Answer (score 0):

use the scanner class and the method nextLine().it will help you a lot
in case if it seems a bit difficult. then read the file line by line and then use *RegEx* pattern to check your required pattern for that line of file.